# SQLite. Из программы на Java срабатывает запрос, который срабатывать не должен

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

У меня есть таблица TableA, в ней есть первичный ключ id. Во второй таблице TableB есть внешний ключ id_TableA. Когда я пишу запрос в SQLiteStudio для добавления в таблицу TableB записи, в которой значение поля id_TableA такое, которого нет в таблице TableA у поля id, естественно вываливается ошибка, так и должно быть. Однако когда я делаю абсолютно идентичный запрос из программы на Java, некорректная строка почему то спокойно добавляется в таблицу TableB. В чем может быть дело?

```
String querySQL = "INSERT INTO TableB(...) VALUES(...)";
Connection connection = hikariDataSource.getConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(querySQL);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Вероятно, нужно включить поддержку внешних ключей (по умолчанию она выключена). Как именно это делается - ищите в документации вашей библиотеки (провайдера) для работы с sqlite.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решилась!

Answer (score 1):

Для решения проблемы в Java необходимо дополнительно добавить поддержку внешних ключей. В моём случае это сделано так:

```
SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.enforceForeignKeys(true);
hikariDataSource.setDataSourceProperties(config.toProperties());
```